# 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' error when add implementation apache library

Tags: android, apache, android-studio

`More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'`

Above error occurs while building when I add implementation Apache lib

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.6'
}
```

Comment: please start a bounty